# Inequality involving ArcTan

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

How to prove that for $x\in[0, +\infty]$ the following inequality is true: $$\arctan x\geq\frac{3 x}{1+2\sqrt{1+x^2}}?$$
I don't have idea from where to start, so any hint is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is known as the Shafer-Fink inequality.
[Here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.0753) you may find different proofs and some improvements, too.

Comment: (+1) Very interesting! I don't know this inequality is named.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say $x=\tan \theta$, so that:
$$\theta \geq \frac{3\tan \theta}{1+2\sqrt{1+\tan^2 \theta}}$$
$\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}=\sec\theta$ because the range of $\arctan x$ always has $\cos \theta > 0$:
$$\theta \geq \frac{3\tan \theta}{1+2\sec\theta}$$
Multiply both the numerator and denominator by $\cos \theta$:
$$\theta \geq \frac{3\sin\theta}{\cos\theta+2}$$
Now, these two functions intersect at $\theta=0$. Also, $\theta$ always has a derivative of $1$, so if we can prove that the derivative of $\frac{3\sin\theta}{\cos\theta+2}$ is always $\leq 1$, we can prove this inequality for $\theta \geq 0$.

$$\frac{d}{d\theta}\frac{3\sin\theta}{\cos\theta+2}=\frac{(\cos\theta+2)\frac{d}{d\theta}(3\sin\theta)-3\sin\theta\frac{d}{d\theta}(\cos\theta+2)}{(\cos\theta+2)^2}$$
$$\frac{d}{d\theta}\frac{3\sin\theta}{\cos\theta+2}=\frac{3\cos^2 \theta+6\cos\theta+3\sin^2\theta}{(\cos\theta+2)^2}=\frac{3+6\cos\theta}{(\cos\theta+2)^2}$$
Now, we need to prove that this is less than or equal to $1$, which is the same as proving:
$$3+6\cos\theta \leq (\cos\theta+2)^2$$
Expand the right side:
$$3+6\cos\theta \leq \cos^2\theta+4\cos\theta+4$$
Subtract both sides by the left side:
$$0 \leq \cos^2\theta-2\cos\theta+1$$
Factor the right side:
$$0 \leq (\cos\theta-1)^2$$
Now, this inequality is obviously true because $0 \leq u^2$ for all $u \in \Bbb{R}$, so we have proven that the derivative of $\frac{3\sin\theta}{\cos\theta+2}$ is always $\leq 1$, so since $\theta$ and that funciton intersect at $\theta=0$, we can conclude that:
$$\theta \geq 0 \implies \theta \geq \frac{3\sin\theta}{\cos\theta+2}$$
$$\theta \geq 0 \implies \theta \geq \frac{3\tan \theta}{1+2\sqrt{1+\tan^2 \theta}}$$
$$x \geq 0 \implies \arctan x \geq \frac{3x}{1+2\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

Comment: Unfortunately, it's the reverse inequality which is true, because $\tan\theta$ is convex on $[0,\frac\pi2]$. Note the Taylor's series  of $\tan\theta$ is not alternating.

Comment: @Bernard I've changed my answer above. Is it correct now? I used this fact: $$\left(f(y)=g(y) \wedge (\forall x \geq y)(f'(y) \geq g'(y))\right) \implies (\forall x \geq y)(f(x) \geq g(x))$$ I am pretty sure this is true because it makes intuitive sense, but I've never seen it used before, so I'm not sure. Here, $f(\theta)=\theta$ and $g(\theta)=\frac{3\sin\theta}{2+\cos\theta}$.

Comment: It's an easy corollary to the *Mean Value theorem* (except the inequality on derivatives is for derivatives at $x$, not $y$). That said, yeur answer is fine now for me (+1).

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for making sure!

Comment: I explicitly quoted the corollary in one of my answers but I can't remember when nor where…

Comment: @Bernard I think I see how it's true now, though. If we look at $h(\theta)=f(\theta)-g(\theta)$, we know $h(y)=0$ and for any $x > y$, $h'(x) \geq 0$. By MVT, there is some $y < x_0 < x$ such that $$h'(x_0)=\frac{h(x)-h(y)}{x-y} \implies h(x)=h(y)+(x-y)h'(x_0)=(x-y)h'(x_0)$$ Since $x > y$, $x-y > 0$ and since $x_0 > y$, $h'(x_0) \geq 0$, so we have $h(x) \geq 0$, or $f(x)-g(x) \geq 0$, or $f(x) \geq g(x)$. Thanks for all of your help!